# Qual a diferença de se colocar -g nas instalações de pacotes por npm, webpack, etc...?

Tags: npm

Já faz um certo tempo que instalo pacotes via **prompt** com **npm, bower** entre outros gerenciadores de pacote, mas nunca entendi direito para que serve a comando **`-g`**. Sei que significa **global**, instalando os pacotes globalmente no computador e não apenas localmente no projeto especificamente. Mas minhas dúvidas são:

> **1** - Com o uso de **-g** onde ficam alocados no computador os pacotes instalados?
>
> **2** - Se instalar por exemplo o Vue.js assim `npm install -g @vue-cli` em um projeto, e em outro projeto utilizando Vue.js instalá-lo com o comando `npm install @vue-cli`, da onde é buscado o Vue, do repositório da internet ou do meu computador?
>
> **3** - Se instalar o Vue.js em um projeto globalmente com uma determinada versão e por acaso instalar ele novamente globalmente com uma versão mais nova em outro projeto, o primeiro projeto que está utilizando a versão antiga poderá gerar problemas, o último sobrescreve o anterior ou são alocados dois Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A principal diferença entre instalar um pacote globalmente é que você passa a executar os comandos na linha de comando, segundo o [doc do npm])https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally#how-to-install-global-packages):

> There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally. Choose which kind of installation to use based on how you want to use the package.
>
> If you want to use a package as a command line tool, then install it globally. This way, it works no matter which directory is current. This is the choice you would use if you were installing grunt, for example.
>
> If you want to depend on the package from your own module, then install it locally. This is the choice you would use if you are using require statements, for example.

Traduzido fica assim:

> Existem duas maneiras de instalar pacotes: localmente ou globalmente. Escolha que tipo de instalação baseado em como você quer utilizar o pacote.
>
> Se você quer usar o pacote como uma ferramenta de linha de comando, então instale o comando globalmente. Desta maneira, o comando funciona independente de qual diretório você está. Esta é a escolha que você usuário se estivesse instalando o grunt, por exemplo.
>
> Se você quer depender do pacote no seu próprio modulo, então instale-o localmente. Esta é a escolha que você usaria para caso estiver usando require, por exemplo.

1. Depende do sistema operacional e da configuração realizada, mas geralmente os pacotes ficam localizados dentro da pasta do usuário.

   - MacOS: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
   - Windows: \AppData\Roaming\npm
2. Não entendi bem a pergunta `de onde é buscado`. Ambos comandos `npm i` com ou sem `-g` irão baixar o último pacote estável publicado no NPM, lembrando que a versão do pacote que será baixado pode ser outra dependendo do seu arquivo `package.json`. [Documentação](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description)
3. Se você instalar o `vue` globalmente não vai fazer diferença pois esse pacote precisa estar instalado localmente (ao menos que você realize um `npm link` porque ai ele passar a buscar o pacote no global). [Documentação](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

   - Não tem problema você atualizar o vue-cli pois é uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento.
   - Quando você fala em instalar o Vue.js globalmente, você diz instalar o pacote vue-cli, certo? Geralmente não se instala os pacotes cli localmente porque ele é uma ferramenta para utilizar via command line, de acordo com a [documentação](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/#cli) deles:

     > The CLI (@vue/cli) is a globally installed npm package and provides the vue command in your terminal. It provides the ability to quickly scaffold a new project via vue create, or instantly prototype new ideas via vue serve. You can also manage your projects using a graphical user interface via vue ui. We will walk through what it can do in the next few sections of the guide.

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar man.Conforme sua resposta para a segunda pergunta, então pq instalar globalmente, se em outro projeto ele baixa de novo do NPM, para que então instalar globalmente? Não entendi a diferença entre as duas instalações.

Comment: Quando executamos o `npm i ` em outro projeto, o npm vai baixar os pacotes definidos no arquivo de configuração `packages.json`. Traduzi a primeira citação do documento do NPM. Veja se fica mais claro.